# 11.1*9 = 99.89999999999999

Tags: google-chrome, math, safari

I am using javascript to calculate a basket total for a simple html5 application. But javascript giving me wrong result in mobile and pc side.

Tested in Safari and Chrome in Mac and Chrome in Android.

For example:
9.1*9= 81.89999999999999
11.1*9= 99.89999999999999

What can i do :D

Comment: What do you mean by "wrong result" ? Do you want values like 9.1*9 = 81.9 and 11.1*9=99.9 ?

Comment: See also [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/238704)

Answer (score 0):

Using Number.tofixed(n)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

```
(9.1 * 9).toFixed(2) = "81.90"
```